# How to match asterisk in string using TCL regexp?

Tags: tcl

I am parsing a text file having content as below :

abcd something
pqrs some other thing
lib/perl
lib/perl/

*lib/perl/user123/*
lib/perl/user456*
again something

My requirement is to match all lib/perl patterns/lines separately using regex in if-else block. The code I have written is only matching only the first if block for all such lib/perl patterns.

```
    set f [open content.txt]
    
    while {[gets $f line] != -1 } { 
      if {[regexp {lib/perl} $line all]} { 
        puts "mactches 1st if"
      } elseif {[regexp {lib/perl/\\*\s*} $line all ]} { 
        puts "matches 1st elseif"
      } elseif {[regexp {lib/perl/.*/\\*\s*} $line all ]} { 
        puts "matches 1st elseif"
      } elseif {[regexp {lib/perl/\w+\\*\s*} $line all ]} { 
        puts "matches 1st elseif"
      }
    }
    close $f
```

How can I make the above code match each lib/perl string separately in separate if-else blocks so that it is not generalized by the mere presence of lib/perl in the line.

Note: I changed the order of the if-else , still a bit of generalization is happening between lib/perl/user123/* and lib/perl/user456*

Thanks

Comment: you probably should not use `*` it actually means match any character and can cause problems, depending on the version of regex used in TD, you should be ok with `[\w\d]+` will match all alphanumeric with control you can also use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+

Comment: You'll never see any of the `matches Nth elseif` -- the first `{lib/perl}` pattern will match first. Put the most specific regexes first, or don't use `elseif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two easy ways to match a literal `*` in a regular expression:

1. Use a backslash to quote it: `\*`
2. Use a character set to quote it: `[*]`

In both cases, you don't need anything else in a Tcl regexp, but make sure that the RE is in braces unless you like handling all the extra backslashes you'll need.